# Running a MDCS on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, mosaic-dataset

I have a MDCS. The script runs without problems in Windows, starting it with a batch file.
The aim is to have it running on ArcGIS Server. How can I run it from a toolbox script?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a toolbox, importing MDCS.py and calling it's main()-function with the two parameters.
The list needs to have at least 2 elements, one of them being the path to the xml file (because the command line or batch file delivers the mdcs.py path as one parameter). The execute script of the toolbox could be:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '...\mdcs-folder\scripts')
import arcpy
import MDCS
from pathlib import Path
import os

def ScriptTool(param0):
    config = "...\mdcs-folder\Parameter\Config\name.xml")).as_posix() 
    list = ["x", f"-i:{config}"]
    argc = len(liste)
    MDCS.main(argc, list)
    pass
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ordner_neue_Raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    ScriptTool(param0)
```

Half the answer is also given in this video at 23:14, but the script is not shown entirely...but it is probably more elegant.

https://mediaspace.esri.com/meia/t/1_q98qok22